# Dtermine whether the integral is convergent or divergent, using the Comparison Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

Using the Comparison Theorem to determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent. I don't know how to change the form.

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-0.1}}dx$$

Here, I tried to find what's higher or lower and all attempts were futile.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th3E4.png)

I couldn't find other formations anymore. I want to receive some tips to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac1{\sqrt{{x^3-0.1}}}\leq c\frac 1{\sqrt{x^3}}$ for some $c>0$ and sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: I don't think 1/root x^3-0.1 is lower than c X 1/root x^3.  root x^3-0.1 is lower than root x^3, then 1/root x^3-0.1 is higher than c X 1/root x^3. could you give me some more details?

Comment: @user335567 $2(x^3-0.1)\geq x^3$ when $x>1$

Comment: why do you think that?.. when x>1, then 2(x^3-1)>1.8 and x^3>1 but it doesn't mean that 2(x^3-1) > x^3. it just means it would be possible for 2(x^3-1) to be higher than x^3. Could you explain it more concretely?

Comment: @user335567 $2(x^3-0.1)= x^3+(x^3-0.2)\geq x^3+0.8$ Are you in middle school?

Comment: i'm not. thank you. you're a genius